# Select a chain of certificates instead of a single certificate (.NET TcpClient)?

Tags: .net, ssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

The [LocalCertificateSelectionCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.localcertificateselectioncallback?view=net-6.0) selects an [X509Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate?view=net-6.0) to be verified by the other side. Is there a way to pass a [chain of certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain?view=net-6.0) instead?

This way, a server with only the Root CA in its trusted store would be able to verify my client, whose certificate was issued by an Intermediate CA.

Comment: After looking at this for some time, the only thing I can think of is to recreate the `X509Certificate` object from base64 using the full chain. Does it definitely not pass the full chain automatically?

Comment: @Charlieface Yes thank you I think that exactly answers my question; your searching skills are better than mine